# Multiple submits in an HTML form

Tags: html, xhtml, semantic-markup

I have an HTML form that needs multiple submit buttons, like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="1"/>
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="2"/>
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="3"/>
```

The problem is that I want it to display on the button something other than what is in the value attribute (in the example above: 1, 2, 3). For example, I want to show "Bar" for the button with value="1". Is this possible?

I've considered using the `<button>` tag, like this:

```
<button name="foo" value="1">Bar</button>
```

The problem with using `<button>` (from w3schools):

> If you use the  element in an HTML form, different browsers
>   may submit different values. Internet Explorer, prior version 9, will
>   submit the text between the  and  tags, while other
>   browsers will submit the content of the value attribute. Use the
>    element to create buttons in an HTML form.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each of the buttons a unique name and then check for their existence in the POST vars instead. Then you can set the value to whatever you want.

Comment: So the name attribute possibly contains the value I really need and the value attribute contains what to display on the button? These values I need will be dynamically assigned during the form generation. Trying to reverse the process in the form handler will make things harder than it needs to be. Seems very hackish, no?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: Yes, it is kind of hackish, but I don't think there's another way unless you want to use JavaScript. You can set the value of a hidden input when it's clicked, if you prefer. Or if you're using PHP on the backend set the name to `name="submit[value_i_want]"` then extract the key out of `$_POST['submit']`

Answer (score -1):

Every button must have unique name so that you can set any value/values to one or more buttons. eg

```
 <input type = "button" name = "foo1" value = "Bar1">
<input type = "button" name = "foo2" value = "Bar2">
<input type = "button" name = "foo3" value = "Bar3">
```

implement it..

Comment: The name attribute does not have to be unique. That restriction is for the id attribute.

Comment: And remember, I want the value submitted via POST/GET to be something other than what is in the value attribute. However, I need the button to display something other than what is sent via POST/GET.

Comment: Also, type="button" means the form will not submit. I need it to submit. No JS.